# MQTT Publish/Subscribe using AWS-IOT doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have written two programs - Publisher and Subscriber.
However, I don't see that subscriber is getting subscribed to the topic.
Also, the subscriber isn't receiving any messages/payload.
I am unsure on how to fix this?

I have verified the endpoints and certificates and it seems to be fine.

Publisher code -

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl
import time

# Define variables

MQTT_PORT = 8883
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 45
MQTT_TOPIC = "driveLedTopic"


MQTT_HOST = "a3p01azi7xqox0-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
CA_ROOT_CERT_FILE = "root-CA.crt"
THING_CERT_FILE = "MyFirstThing.cert.pem"
THING_PRIVATE_KEY = "MyFirstThing.private.key"

# Define on_publish event function

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print "Message Published..."

#Initiate MQTT client
mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# Regiser publish callback function
mqttc.on_publish = on_publish

# Configure TLS Set
mqttc.tls_set(CA_ROOT_CERT_FILE, certfile=THING_CERT_FILE,
              keyfile=THING_PRIVATE_KEY, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
              tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

# Connect with MQTT Broker
mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)
mqttc.loop_start()

counter = 0

while True:
    print("Publish Message")
    mqttc.publish(MQTT_TOPIC, "Hello User ", qos=1)
    time.sleep(10)

mqttc.disconnect()
```

Subscriber code -

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl

# Define Variables

MQTT_PORT = 8883
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 45
MQTT_TOPIC = "driveLedTopic"


MQTT_HOST = "a3p01azi7xqox0-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
CA_ROOT_CERT_FILE = "root-CA.crt"
THING_CERT_FILE = "MyFirstThing.cert.pem"
THING_PRIVATE_KEY = "MyFirstThing.private.key"

# Define on connect event function
# We shall subscribe to our Topic in this function


def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
    mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC, 0)

# Define on_message event function.
# This function will be invoked every time,
# a new message arrives for the subscribed topic


def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
    print("Topic: " + str(msg.topic))
    print("QoS: " + str(msg.qos))
    print("Payload: " + str(msg.payoad))



def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed to Topic: ")

# Initiate MQTT Client


mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# Assign event callbacks

mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

# Configure TLS Set
mqttc.tls_set(CA_ROOT_CERT_FILE, certfile=THING_CERT_FILE,
              keyfile=THING_PRIVATE_KEY, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
              tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

# Connect with MQTT Broker
mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)


# Continue Monitoring the incoming messages for subscribed topic
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Comment: There is a **Test** function in the IOT management console for publishing and subscribing to a topic. If you subscribe in the console, do your Published messages appear?

Comment: No, In the IOT console I have put - driveLedTopic in the topic column. Does it need to have some slash or something more?

Comment: Some things you could try: Start by subscribing in the console, then sending a message via the console. It should work fine. Then, try sending a message with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`aws iot-data publish` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/publish.html) and see if it appears in the subscription. Then, try it via your program. This might also help: [Example Mosquitto CLI pub/sub using AWS IoT MQTT endpoint](https://gist.github.com/lashex/12b6fa8327fc07e191d387290e81d39e)